# Programatically check a CSI driver's capabilities

Tags: kubernetes, containers

How can I check what capabilities a CSI driver has? One way I know is to parse the following html page:

https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/drivers.html

But I would like to know if there is a a better way / API call to query this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any API that contains that kind of information and based on this disclaimer:

> DISCLAIMER: Information in this table has not been validated by
> Kubernetes SIG-Storage. Users who want to use these CSI drivers need
> to contact driver maintainers for driver capabilities.

I highly doubt that there is one. For checking available Kubernetes API resources you may want to have a look at the [API reference](https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/).